# Disable wheel scroll zooming with ArcGIS Javascript API 4.11

Tags: zoom, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, disable

I want to disable wheel scroll zooming so the viewer can scroll down the page without losing the cursor in the map.

But this code freezes scrolling altogether, so when the cursor is over the map, there is no scrolling at all.

```
view.on("mouse-wheel", function(event) {
          // disable mouse wheel scroll zooming on the view
          event.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Codepen is https://codepen.io/nadinetrahan/full/VNYxRg

Answer (score 1):

Try using the code example from [here](https://community.esri.com/thread/177970#comment-612463) instead:

```
view.surface.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {   
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();  
}, true);
```

Demo of the two [here](https://codepen.io/gavinr/pen/OGmEGb?editors=1000).

Comment: Where is view.surface documented?

Comment: Thanks Gavin, that does continue to scroll over the map if you start the scroll out of it. But if you stop scrolling on the map, then start again, the zoom kicks in.